# Funções + listas em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quando eu tento criar a função abaixo eu sempre recebo o **primeiro** valor da lista, parece que ela não é iterada. Alguém poderia me explicar o por que?

Segue o código:

```py
novalista = []

def find_it(seq):
    number_list = seq
    for number in number_list:
        novalista.append(number)
        return novalista

print(find_it([2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))
```

`novalista != number_list` (Por que?)

O `print` mostra isto:

```
[2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplesmente por que o `return` da função esta dentro do `for`, se tu colocar fora vai retorna a lista completa.

```
novalista = []

def find_it(seq):
    number_list = seq
    for number in number_list:
        novalista.append(number)
    return novalista

print(find_it([2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))
```

Answer (score 3):

O principal problema que colabora para o comportamento que citou é que a sua indentação está errada e, como consequência disso, o `return` está dentro do seu laço de repetição. Assim, ele finalizará a função já na primeira iteração do laço.

Mas não se limita a isso, há outros problemas no código que gerarão efeitos colaterais que talvez ainda nem havia percebido.

```
novalista = []

def find_it(seq):
    number_list = seq
    for number in number_list:
        novalista.append(number)
    return novalista  # Indentação corrigida

print(find_it([2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))
```

Outro problema é que você modifica a lista `novalista` que foi definida fora da sua função, no escopo global (aparentemente). Como consequência disso, você não conseguirá chamar a função novamente, pois haverá "lixo" no retorno da mesma.

```
>>> fint_id([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]

>>> find_it([4, 5, 6])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Perceba que o retorno da sua primeira chamada permaneceu gerando uma saída inesperada na segunda execução da função.

Para resolver, o ideal é modificar um objeto definido localmente:

```
def find_it(seq):
    novalista = []
    number_list = seq
    for number in number_list:
        novalista.append(number)
    return novalista  # Indentação corrigida
```

Outros pontos que valem menção são:

1. Você chama a função de `find_it` que retorna basicamente uma cópia de uma lista; não fez muito sentido (nome "buscar por" que retorna uma cópia da lista sem fazer uma busca).
2. Dentro da função fez `number_list = seq`, isso também não há justificativas para fazer, você apenas definiu um novo nome para sua lista original apenas para iterá-la; poderia iterar diretamente `seq` produzindo o mesmo resultado.
3. Ora você nomeia suas estruturas em inglês, ora em português, seria interessante manter um padrão.
4. Ora você nomeia suas estruturas utilizando o *underline* como separador, ora coloca todas as palavras juntas, também seria interessante manter um padrão (aqui, como convenção definida na PEP 8, no Python costuma-se separar com o `_`).

Se a intenção é realmente fazer uma cópia da lista, há outras formas melhores e mais simples de fazer:

```
nova_lista = lista.copy()
```

Comment: Ótima resposta Anderson, muito obrigado!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Na verdade está misturado inglês e português e muitas coisas não fazem sentido porque este não era o propósito do código, fiz isto apenas para demonstrar um problema que eu estava tendo com outro programa ahahah. Muito obrigado pelo feedback! Suas dicas para iniciantes como eu também são muito preciosas, abraços.